# Shifter Barbarian rage and Shifting combo?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian

how does rage and Shifting mechanic work are they fine being used together or is there something in rage info that I've missed that says its not allowed?

Link for shifter information-

http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Eberron_v1.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything that would disallow it. I've taken a look through the shifter rules and the barbarian rage ability:

---

**Rage**

Rage has a few governing factors. The important points are

> - Use a bonus action to start
> - Do not gain certain benefits if wearing heavy armor
> - Cannot cast spells or maintain concentration
> - Lasts one minute, or until ended

---

**Shifters**

> - Shift takes a bonus action to begin
> - Lasts a minute, or until ended

Most importantly, the shift is not described as a spell. As such, it seems like there shouldn't be any issues with rageshifting.